# Finding the last value of a quadratic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\large 2,6,12,20,30, \ldots, a_n $$
Above shows the first few numbers of an increasing series. If the sum of these numbers equals $32430$, find the value of $a_n$.

My progress.

I defined the sequence as a quadratic sequence with general term $t_n = n^{2}+n$

I tried playing with the numbers and saw that the following emerged:

$$ 1+1  ; 3+3 ; 6 + 6 ; 10 + 10 ; 15 + 15 ; ... ; \frac{1}{2} \times a_n + \frac{1}{2} \times a_n$$
I decided to divide the sequence by $2$ which means the sum will equal $16215$. I grouped the sum with the new sequence as follows:
$$1 + 3 + 6 + 10 + ...$$
$$ = 4 + 16 + 36 + 64 + ... $$
$$ =2^{2} + 4^{2} + 6^{2} + 8^{2} + ... $$
Which is equal to $16215$. Can someone help me proceed please?

Comment: It can't be equal to $16215$, since the sum is clearly even. This means $n/2$ is odd and you can't fully group $1+3+6+10+\cdots$ into squares like that.

Comment: Why not? It is symmetry.

Comment: A shortcut is to note  that $(n+1)^3-n^3=3n(n+1)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No it itsn't: It is $3n^2+3n+1$.

Comment: There are no cubes in the sequence that I can spot.

Comment: @AspiringMathlete You can have e.g. $1+3+6+10+15=2^2+4^2+15$, and $15$ is not a square.

Comment: $15 + 21 = 36 = 6^{2} $

Comment: @AspiringMathlete If it were true that you have $2^2+4^2+6^2+\cdots + (2k)^2$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, then you'd have the sum even, but clearly $16215$ is odd, so we can't have the summation in this form and the last member is not a square and is odd.

Comment: @wythagoras: I forgot to subtract $1$. But same idea.

Answer (score 1):

We will assume that the first term is $a_1$. Note that 
$$a_n=n(n+1)=\frac{(n+1)^3-n^3-1}{3}.$$
Add up from $1$ to $n$, noting the cancellations (almost telescoping). The result is 
$$\frac{(n+1)^3-1-n}{3},$$
so we are solving 
$$(n+1)^3-(n+1)=97290.$$
Thus, approximately, $n+1=\sqrt[3]{97290}\approx 45.99$. It looks as if $n+1$ might be $46$. Plugging in, we see that it is exactly $46$. So $n=45$,  and now we know $a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=(1^2+1)+(2^2+2)+\cdots+(n^2+n)$

$=(1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2)+(1+2+\cdots+n)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=32430$

$\!\iff\! n(2n^2+3n+1)+3n^2+3n-6\cdot 32430=0$

$\!\iff\! 2n^3+6n^2+4n-2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 23\cdot 47=0$

So $2n\mid 2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 23\cdot 47\!\iff\! n\mid 2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 23\cdot 47$.

You check these divisors of $2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 23\cdot 47$ in increasing order:

$1,2,3,5,6,9,10,15,18,30,\boxed{45}$.

Comment: Did the last step use the integer root theorem? You might want to mention that.

Comment: @wythagoras No, it used basic divisibility. $2n$ divides the other terms, so must divide $2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 23\cdot 47$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=a_{n-1}+2n$ with $a_1=2$. Hence, $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n= \sum_{i=1}^{N} 2 \sum_{k=1}^{i} k = 2 \sum_{i=1}^{N} {i \choose 2}=2{N+1 \choose 3}$. Hence we are looking for $N$ such that ${N+1 \choose 3}=16215$. $(N+1)(N)(N-1)=97290$. But $(N+1)(N)(N-1)-N^3=N$. So $\lceil(97290)^{(1/3)}\rceil=N$. Whence, $N=46$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i^2+i) = \dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$$
which you want to be $32430 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 23 \cdot 47$.
So one of $n, n+1, n+2$ is divisible by $5$, one is divisible by $23$ and one is divisible by $47$.
Since $23 \times 2 = 46$, this suggests either $n=45$, $n+1=46$, $n+2=47$ or 
$n=46$, $n+1=47$, $n+2=48$.  The latter doesn't work because none is divisible by $5$.  The first does work.